# How would I formulate an insert query into another database using postgres_fdw?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgres-fdw

Here is the query that I want to run - Let's the current database that I am running this query in is db1 and the database in which I want to insert records is db2.

```
  insert into db2.employee(id, name, group) values(id, <db1.employee.name>, <db1.employee.group>) where id in (select id from archived limit 2);
```

As you can see, the values have to be selected from employee table of db1 (current database) and then inserted into employee table of db2.

I know the query is wrong - but I have just written to explain what I am trying to do.

How would I formulate a query using postgres_fdw?

I have tried doing something the other way round using this query

```
INSERT INTO  employee select * from 
dblink('host=10.1.1.1
 user=user
 password=password
 dbname=mydb', 'select * from employee') tt(
       id int,
  name character varying,
 );
```

Edit: PLEASE Note that I want to do a remote insert and a local select.
It seems like I am able to achieve this using the query above when I run the query in db2 as my local database instead of db1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access tables in a different database directly like you can do in MySQL (a MySQL *database* corresponds to a PostgreSQL *schema*).

So maybe you can achieve what you want either by using different schemas in a single database.

If you really need to update a table in a different database, you'll have to use the postgres_fdw foreign data wrapper to access the foreign table.

You'll have to define a foreign table – let's call it `foreign_employee` – in database `db1` that points to a table in `db2`.

Then you could do it like that:

```
INSERT INTO foreign_employee
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
     JOIN archived a USING id
LIMIT 2;
```

Note that the `LIMIT` is a bit strange here, since there is no implicit order in a query result unless you force one with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: and then inserting rows into the actual table - db2.employee from the foreign table - how to do that?

Comment: `db2.employee` *is* the foreign table, no? If you want to insert into two tables use something like `WITH x AS (INSERT ... RETURNING ...) INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM x`.

Comment: db2.employee is an actual table - which exists in db2. It has the same schema as db1.employee

Comment: Do I need a foreign table even though I have an exact replica of that table in the db2?

Comment: I have updated my question with Edit 1 to explain further what I am trying to do

Comment: I expounded a bit, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Hmmm may be I am not understanding but I cannot figure out what the query will be when I have to read the foreign table and insert data in the actual employee table in db2? Which database should this query be run and what will it look like?

Comment: I do not understand at all. Maybe you should rewrite the question and state precisely which table is where and where you want the query to run.