# Logging records in a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am having trouble thinking of a way to copy three fields out of a database into and append them to another table along with the current date. Basically what I want to do is:
DB-A:  ID (N9), Name (C69),  Phone (N15) {and a list of other fields I dont care about}
DB-B:  Date (Todays date/time), Nane, Address, Phone (as above)

Would be great is this was a trigger in the DB on add or update of DB-A.

Greg

Comment: Hey Greg, can you post the create table statements, so that we can better visualize the problem?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but this answers your question, except for the trigger part, which you can find in the manual.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589822/how-would-i-formulate-an-insert-query-into-another-database-using-postgres-fdw

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/postgres-fdw.html or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html are options. Although I do have a preference for `postgres_fdw`

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty using `postgres_fdw`

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw ;
CREATE SERVER extern_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'foreignserver.co.uk', port '5432', dbname 'mydb');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR myuser SERVER extern_server OPTIONS (user 'anotheruser');

-- Creating a foreign table based on table t1 at the server described above
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_t1 (
  dba INT,
  name VARCHAR(9),
  phone VARCHAR(15) 
)
SERVER extern_server OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 't1');

--Inserting data to a new table + date
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT dba,name,phone,CURRENT_DATE FROM foreign_t1;
-- Or just retrieving what you need placing the current date as a column
SELECT dba,name,phone,CURRENT_DATE FROM foreign_t1;
```